# zsh: command not found: dcos

Tags: docker, vagrant, dcos

I tried to install DC/OS cluster on my Mac by [dcos-vagrant](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant).

Intsallation is quite smooth, no errors found.

```
==> m1: sudo: chmod u+x /opt/mesosphere/bin/postflight.sh
==> m1: sudo: /opt/mesosphere/bin/postflight.sh
==> boot: DC/OS Installation Complete
==> boot: Web Interface: http://m1.dcos/
```

but when I opne the `http://m1.dcos/`, doesn't show the web-ui, show the `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error, and cannot find the dcos command.

> GET http://m1.dcos/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

```
➜  dcos-vagrant git:(master) dcos marathon app add https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/usage/nginx.json
zsh: command not found: dcos
```

Anyone can help me! Thanks in advance!

---

dcos cannot work duo to I didn't install the dcos CLI.

> [intallation DC/OS CLI](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/usage/cli/install/)

Comment: I *think* we implicitly require/assume bash, let me check

Comment: dcos can work right now when I Install the CLI, but the webpage doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install the CLI, copy and paste into your terminal:

```
mkdir -p dcos
cd dcos
curl -O https://downloads.dcos.io/dcos-cli/install.sh 
bash ./install.sh . https://m1.dcos
source ./bin/env-setup
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty response from http://m1.dcos/ would seem to indicate the UI service or admin router is having issues, but the CLI working means admin router is reachable and correctly proxying components like Marathon & Mesos.

You might check the admin router logs to see if it's having trouble serving the UI html/js.

Status:

```
systemctl status dcos-adminrouter.service
```

Logs:

```
journalctl -u dcos-adminrouter
```